# MySQL Fulltext Query Returning Error, Index Created

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, full-text-search

I have created a table named `users`, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   u_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   u_namefirst VARCHAR(100),
   u_namelast VARCHAR(100),
   u_email VARCHAR(100),
   FULLTEXT (u_namefirst, u_namelast, u_email)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

And populated it with data:

```
INSERT INTO users (u_namefirst, u_namelast, u_email) VALUES
('Michael','Williams','williams@williams.com'),
('Jon','Test','test@test.com'),
('Jane','Smith','smith@smith.com'),
('Fred','Francis','fred@fred.com'),
('Mike','Williams','mike@williams.com'),
('Michael','Burke','michael@burke.com');
```

Yet, when I run:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE MATCH ( u_namelast ) AGAINST ( 'williams');
```

I get: "Error Code: 1191. Can't Find FULLTEXT index matching the column list". The index definitely exists and its type is definitely Fulltext. The correct columns have been selected for that index.

I have tried running both InnoDB and MyISAM engines and I get the same result. As a test, when I exchange the last line for `WHERE u_namefirst = 'michael'` I get a correct result -- so I don't believe it is a problem with the existing data.

I'm running MySQL 5.6.16 (x86_64) on Windows 7 Ultimate.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please show the `create table` statement and any other statements used to create the index.  The obvious assumption is that the index does not really exist.

Comment: The table was originally imported from an Access file. The index was created with MySQL Workbench with the following code:
`ALTER TABLE 'system'.'user' ADD FULLTEXT INDEX 'search' ('firstname' ASC);`

Comment: My guess, based on the use of single quotes, is that the index was never created.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Use backticks to quote table and column names in MySQL.

Comment: I dropped the index and recreated it as follows: `ALTER TABLE user ADD FULLTEXT INDEX search ( firstname ASC );` (without the single quotes, as suggested). This successfully created the index, but the 1191 error message still comes up when I match against. Could the fact that it was imported from Access be causing any issues?

Comment: I tried backticks too. Same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Problem**

Your problem seems to be (from running the code you've been posting) mixing up of column names. You added a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on the `firstname` column:

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD FULLTEXT INDEX search ( firstname ASC );
```

Then when you query, you're searching against the surname field **which as no index**:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE MATCH ( u_namelast ) AGAINST ( 'williams');
```

**The solution**

Either indexing the correct column, or querying the correct column should work just fine. Be sure to use the correct engine (MyISAM). You can [read more about FULLTEXT indexes with MyISAM on the MySQL documentation site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

**Example**

Using the below example code I've given you a few options that will work, I've included the ALTER TABLE line so you can see that method works fine also.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   u_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   u_namefirst VARCHAR(100),
   u_namelast VARCHAR(100),
   u_email VARCHAR(100),
   FULLTEXT (u_namefirst, u_namelast, u_email)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

ALTER TABLE users ADD FULLTEXT INDEX search ( u_namelast ASC );

INSERT INTO users (u_namefirst, u_namelast, u_email) VALUES
('Michael','Williams','williams@williams.com'),
('Jon','Test','test@test.com'),
('Jane','Smith','smith@smith.com'),
('Fred','Francis','fred@fred.com'),
('Mike','Williams','mike@williams.com'),
('Michael','Burke','michael@burke.com');
```

So now we have an index on `u_namefirst, u_namelast, u_email` and one just one `u_namelast`.

You can either query against the individual index

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE MATCH (u_namelast) AGAINST ('Williams');
```

Or query against the one with multiple fields

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE MATCH (u_namefirst, u_namelast, u_email) AGAINST ('Williams');
```

Both should give you the following result

```
1   Michael Williams    williams@williams.com
5   Mike    Williams    mike@williams.com
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex.Ritna for the fantastic and very detailed answer! Strangely the bottom query works but the one above it doesn't. Somehow when matching only the last name the 1191 error returns, but when matching all three of the columns the correct result returns. Any thoughts on why the last name column would cause an error when matched alone?

Comment: Because you don't have a FULLTEXT index on the u_namelast column. In my example I added that on this line: `ALTER TABLE users ADD FULLTEXT INDEX search ( u_namelast ASC );`. Even though you added an index over all 3, doesn't mean you can use one column individually still without an index explicitly on it.

Comment: @Modemmute Consider marking an answer as accepted if it meets the requirements of and resolves your question